# Proving $p^2q+q^2r+r^2p+pq^2+qr^2+rp^2\geq 6pqr$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I am solving a problem about probability and I need to show this inequality:
$$p^2q+q^2r+r^2p+pq^2+qr^2+rp^2\geq 6pqr,$$
where $p,q,r\in[0,1].$

I tried writing it as 
$$p^2(q+r)+p((q+r)^2-8qr)+qr(q+r)\geq 0,$$
or equivalently,
$$p^2(q+r)+p(q+r-2\sqrt{2qr})(q+r+2\sqrt{2qr})+qr(q+r)\geq 0.$$
Since $p,q,r\in[0,1]$, the only thing that remains to check is that
$q+r-2\sqrt{2qr}$ is non-negative, but this need not be true.

**I then tried a second approach:**

I tried using multivariable calculus to find the minimum of 
$$f(p,q,r)=p^2q+q^2r+r^2p+pq^2+qr^2+rp^2-6pqr,$$
but then I get
$$Jf(p,q,r)=\begin{pmatrix}q^2+r^2+2p(q+r)-6qr\\
p^2+r^2+2q(p+r)-6pr\\
p^2+q^2+2r(p+q)-6pq\end{pmatrix},$$
and solving $Jf=\mathbf{0}$ seems quite difficult too.

**Question: Can anyone help with either of the above approaches, or if not, give a hint on how to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM/GM $p^2q+qr^2\ge2pqr$ etc.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed something so obvious...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
p(q-r)^2+q(r-p)^2+r(p-q)^2 \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{cyc}(p^2q+p^2r-2pqr)=\sum_{cyc}r(p-q)^2\geq0.$$